# REGEX preg_split()

Tags: regex

I have an array full of strings that may contain one or more underscores, dashes, and periods.  I want to split the into the characters separated by the  underscores, dashes, and periods. So far I've had success with the underscores and dashes but not the periods.

This works:

```
$family02 = preg_split('/_|-/', $row['family'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

When I try...

```
'/_|-./'
'/_|-\./'
'/_|-|./'
```

...or ordering the delimiters differently, I get splits on 1 of 3 or 2 of 3, or empty arrays.

Thank you for any help or good REGEX links.

Rd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
preg_split('/[-_.]/', $str)
```

which means you are splitting by one of `-`, `_`, `.`

If you want to remove empty groups inside of string, then use

```
preg_split('/[-_.]+/', $str)
```

so multiple determiners apply as one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
// [_.-] stands for a character of underscore or dash or period.
$family02 = preg_split('/[_.-]/', $row['family'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```